# Determine whether each level is monotonically increasing

Tags: r

I need to know if each level of a factor provides increasing values. I've seen [How to check if a sequence of numbers is monotonically increasing (or decreasing)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13093912/how-to-check-if-a-sequence-of-numbers-is-monotonically-increasing-or-decreasing) but don't know how to apply to the single levels only.
Let's say there is the data frame df which is divided into persons. Each person has height over years. Now I want to know if the data set is correct. Therefore I need to know if the height has increasing values - per person:

I tried

```
Results<- by(df, df$person, 
                    function(x) {data = x,
                    all(x == cummax(height))
                    }
  )
```

but it does not work. And

```
Results<- by(df, df$person, 
                    all(height == cummax(height))
                    }
  )
```

also not. I receive that height cannot be found.
What am I doing wrong here?

A small data extraction:

```
Serial_number    Amplification    Voltage
1    608004648    111.997    379.980
2    608004648    123.673    381.968
3    608004648    137.701    383.979
4    608004648    154.514    385.973
5    608004648    175.331    387.980
6    608004648    201.379    389.968
7    608004649    118.753    378.080
8    608004649    131.739    380.085
9    608004649    147.294    382.082
10    608004649    166.238    384.077
11    608004649    189.841    386.074
12    608004649    220.072    388.073
13    608004650    115.474    382.066
14    608004650    127.838    384.063
15    608004650    142.602    386.064
16    608004650    160.452    388.056
17    608004650    182.732    390.060
18    608004650    211.035    392.065
```

`Serial_number` is the factor and I want to check each serial number if the corresponding amplification values are increasing.

Comment: no, by is not needed. I'll add some data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this with a group by operation

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(Serial_number) %>%
   summarise(index = all(sign(Amplification - 
          lag(Amplification, default = first(Amplification))) >= 0))
```

---

Or with `by` from `base R`.  As we are passing the complete dataset, the `x` (anonymous function call object) is the dataset, from which we can extract the column of interest with `$` or `[[`

```
by(df, list(df$Serial_number), FUN = function(x) all(sign(diff(x$Amplification))>=0))
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(index = all(sign(Amplification - shift(Amplification, 
          fill = first(Amplification))) >=0)), .(Serial_number)]
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Serial_number = c(608004648L, 608004648L, 608004648L, 
608004648L, 608004648L, 608004648L, 608004649L, 608004649L, 608004649L, 
608004649L, 608004649L, 608004649L, 608004650L, 608004650L, 608004650L, 
608004650L, 608004650L, 608004650L), Amplification = c(111.997, 
123.673, 137.701, 154.514, 175.331, 201.379, 118.753, 131.739, 
147.294, 166.238, 189.841, 220.072, 115.474, 127.838, 142.602, 
160.452, 182.732, 211.035), Voltage = c(379.98, 381.968, 383.979, 
385.973, 387.98, 389.968, 378.08, 380.085, 382.082, 384.077, 
386.074, 388.073, 382.066, 384.063, 386.064, 388.056, 390.06, 
392.065)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
"16", "17", "18"))
```

Answer (score 2):

What about something like

```
vapply(unique(df$person), 
     function (k) all(diff(df$height[df$person == k]) >= 0), # or '> 0' if strictly mon. incr.
     logical(1))
# returns
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

with

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(person = c("A","B", "C","A","A","C","B"), height = runif(7, 1.75, 1.85))
df
  person   height
1      A 1.778758
2      B 1.828831
3      C 1.790898
4      A 1.838302
5      A 1.844047
6      C 1.754556
7      B 1.802811
```